# How to stop QTreeWidget from creating the item duplicates on Drag and Drop

Tags: python, pyqt

The code below creates `QTreeWidget` with five items.
The `self.setDragDropMode(self.InternalMove)` flag assures that when the item is dragged on top of
another there will be no copy of it made (so the number of items always stay the same).

[image]

If we replace this line with `self.setDragDropMode(self.DragDrop)` then every time an item is dragged/dropped a new copy of will be created.

[image]

Since I don't want a copy of item to be created on every dragAndDrop event I would be happy with `InternalMove` flag if it wouldn't be blocking `QTreeWidget` from accepting the drops from outside of its own view (if `InternalMove` flag is set `QTreeWidget` does not allow dragging-dropping from another `QTreeWidget`, QListView or File Browser).
Is there a way to set an override so `QTreeWidget` doesn't create a duplicate of dragged item and yet allows a dropping from outside of its own window.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

class Tree(QtGui.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Tree, self).__init__()
        self.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.setDropIndicatorShown(True)
        self.setDragDropMode(self.InternalMove)
        items=[QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem([name]) for name in ['Item_1','Item_2','Item_3','Item_4','Item_5']]
        self.addTopLevelItems(items)
        self.resize(360,240)
        self.show()

tree=Tree()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to solving this problem is that you have to implement when the object has moved to the next `QListsWidget` and check whether or not the data is duplicated or not.  Take the data from source to destination by removing the source and adding this data to destination `QListsWidget`.

Use two methods, `dragEnterEvent` and `dropEvent`, to handle them all;

1. Implemented `dragEnterEvent` Check object to move is same `QListsWidget`.
2. Implemented `dropEvent` Check data is duplicated or not  And take data from source to destination.

Example:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class QCustomTreeWidget (QtGui.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(QCustomTreeWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.setDragDropMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.DragDrop)
        self.resize(360,240)

    def dragEnterEvent (self, eventQDragEnterEvent):
        sourceQCustomTreeWidget = eventQDragEnterEvent.source()
        if isinstance(sourceQCustomTreeWidget, QCustomTreeWidget):
            if self != sourceQCustomTreeWidget:
                sourceQCustomTreeWidget.setDragDropMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.DragDrop)
                eventQDragEnterEvent.accept()
            else:
                sourceQCustomTreeWidget.setDragDropMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
                QtGui.QTreeWidget.dragEnterEvent(self, eventQDragEnterEvent)
        else:
            QtGui.QTreeWidget.dragEnterEvent(self, eventQDragEnterEvent)

    def dropEvent (self, eventQDropEvent):
        sourceQCustomTreeWidget = eventQDropEvent.source()
        if isinstance(sourceQCustomTreeWidget, QCustomTreeWidget):
            if self != sourceQCustomTreeWidget:
                sourceQCustomTreeWidget.setDragDropMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.DragDrop)
                sourceQTreeWidgetItem = sourceQCustomTreeWidget.currentItem()
                isFound = False
                for column in range(0, self.columnCount()):
                    sourceQString = sourceQTreeWidgetItem.text(column)
                    listsFoundQTreeWidgetItem = self.findItems(sourceQString, QtCore.Qt.MatchExactly, column)
                    if listsFoundQTreeWidgetItem:
                        isFound = True
                        break
                if not isFound:
                    (sourceQTreeWidgetItem.parent() or sourceQCustomTreeWidget.invisibleRootItem()).removeChild(sourceQTreeWidgetItem)
                    self.invisibleRootItem().addChild(sourceQTreeWidgetItem)
            else:
                sourceQCustomTreeWidget.setDragDropMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
                QtGui.QTreeWidget.dropEvent(self, eventQDropEvent)
        else:
            QtGui.QTreeWidget.dropEvent(self, eventQDropEvent)

class QCustomQWidget (QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        super(QCustomQWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.my1QCustomTreeWidget = QCustomTreeWidget(self)
        self.my2QCustomTreeWidget = QCustomTreeWidget(self)
        items = [QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem([name]) for name in ['Item_1', 'Item_2', 'Item_3', 'Item_4', 'Item_5']]
        self.my1QCustomTreeWidget.addTopLevelItems(items)
        self.allQHBoxLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.allQHBoxLayout.addWidget(self.my1QCustomTreeWidget)
        self.allQHBoxLayout.addWidget(self.my2QCustomTreeWidget)
        self.setLayout(self.allQHBoxLayout)

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
myQCustomQWidget = QCustomQWidget()
myQCustomQWidget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[Useful reference for event handle](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qabstractitemview.html#dragEnterEvent)